# struct hasn't been written to binary file in C++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I want to write some structs to a binary file, but it hasn't been written. It wrote that the file size is greater than 0 buf when I look at it in hex viewer I don't see the structs. It also hasn't been read from it. I know I opened it correctly and I didn't find the problem.

Example:

```cpp
enum CellType
{
    WHITE = 0,
    BLACK = 1,
    EMPTY = 2,
    OUT = 3
};
struct Cell {
    int nRow;
    int nCol;
    CellType type;
};

void main() {
    cout << "enter file name" << endl;

    cin >> fileName;
    ofstream fsBoardBinFile;
    fsBoardBinFile.open(fileName, ios::binary|ios::out);
    Cell s1 = { 1,1,BLACK };
   fsBoardBinFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s1), sizeof(Cell));
    fsBoardBinFile.close();
}
```

Comment: `void main()` --> bug. `main` *always* returns `int`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-constructing them and immediately assigning new values. In particular, this means changing `ofstream fsBoardBinFile; fsBoardBinFile.open(fileName, ios::binary|ios::out);` to `ofstream fsBoardBinFile(fileName, ios::binary|ios::out);`. And you don't need to call `fsBoardBinFile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: `fileName` is not defined in the question. If it is a `std::string`, you can't use `strcat` but can use the `+` operator. If it is intended to be a null-terminated character array, you can use `strcat`, but you have to make sure it's big enough to hold all the characters AND the null terminator.

Comment: You are attempting to convert the address of s1 to a char pointer and then attempting to print that. You are better of just printing the individual elements of your struct. or write a print function that will do that same

Answer (score 0):

Use `int main()` as Jesper Juhl suggested and try
`fsBoardBinFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s1), sizeof(s));`
Also use `+` operator instead of strcat if you are using std::string. Since you have not included what CellType is I deleted it. For just int:

```
fsBoardBinFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s1), sizeof(s1));
```

writes 11(asci:11) not number 1(ascii:49) to file. Using

```
ifstream fsBoardBinFile1(fileName);
    fsBoardBinFile1<<((char*)&s2, sizeof(Cell));
    cout << s2.nRow << s2.nCol << endl;
```

prints 11 to screen so this seems to be working fine. If there's a problem with `CellType` you'll need to update your code to include what it is.

Comment: i added this. it still havent written to the file and i cant find the problem. i saw that it might be with the big endian and little endian settings in my computer.